# Unusual "unknown parameter exception" in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have run into a very unusual exception involving JPA Query object with a hibernate backing, on Spring Frame work, i find it strange for three reasons

1. I am certain the named parameter exist and is not tampered.
2. This works on most of our environment.
3. Query.setParameter() does not throw the exception, but rather  from some sort of interceptor from spring.

Does anybody have an idea?

SQL assembly with the parameter :

```
sql.append(" AND table2.entry_date >= :start_date AND table2.entry_date <= :end_date ");
```

Code where the parameter is set, and appears to be fine.

```
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql.toString(), "XXXXXXXXXXX")
            .unwrap(Query.class);

    query.setParameter("time_zone", filter.getTimeZone());
    query.setParameter("start_date", filter.getStartDate().toLocalDateTime(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown parameter name : start_date; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : start_date
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:367)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at com.redacted.redacted.redacted.redacted.redacted.redacted.redacted.RedactedRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53270333.retrieveReportSlice(<generated>)
```

Comment: If it works in some environments and not others, I'd look at your database schema too (i.e. make sure it's consistent across environments).

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. And the full SQL statement. Preferably create a test case based on that recreating the error.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Why are you unwrapping to a Hibernate `Query`? Why can't you simply work with the standard JPA API here? What is `"XXXXXXXXXXX"`?

Comment: Im afraid this this is a proprietary code, so i have to redact, the XXXXXXXXXX part is a SqlResultSetMapping.

What database? 
 - postgres

Why unwrapping? 
  - weird timestamp conversions happen with no unwrapping.

Comment: And the SQL it is always the same, right? Not dynamic or anything? Because this : sql.append() ... sound like it is dynamic .. and if you try to set the parameter without having it in the SQL it will throw this error @J-darRodriguez

Comment: Can you check it for us, please? @J-darRodriguez

Comment: @Brother yeah i suspected that at first, but the SQL is always correct for all cases under my test.